# Angular2 date pipe to show full date

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using the following to show the date

```
 <p><i class="  zmdi zmdi-calendar icon icon--white-icon "></i>{{event?.date.start | date:'yMMMMEEEEd'}}</p>
```

which displays the date as follows,

```
Saturday, March 18, 2017
```

I need the above with the time too. how should i change the filter?

**Expected output**

Saturday, March 18, 2017 11:29:30 pm

Comment: Read the documentation. It's that easy. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/DatePipe-pipe.html

Comment: I did that ,but this does not have any space between

Comment: You did what? It doesn't have spece between what and what?

Comment: | date:'yMMMMEEEEdjms'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
  <p>
       <i ..."></i>
       {{event?.date.start | date:'EEEE, MMMM dd, y, hh:mm:ss a'}}
  </p>
```

[here is a link to a plunkr that allows you to play with data pipes](https://embed.plnkr.co/bFU6fcz5dY4oRrrXStog/)

Comment: it does not show correct time Saturday, March 18, 2017, 12:30:00 tt

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this out and works fine

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-home',
  template: `

  {{theDate | date:'EEEE, MMMM d, y, H:mm:s a'}} <!-- Output is Friday, February 24, 2017, 12:06:47 PM-->

  `
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  theDate = new Date();

  constructor() {

  }

}
```

The out is is `Friday, February 24, 2017, 12:06:47 PM`

So basically in your case you should have

```
<p>
    <i class="  zmdi zmdi-calendar icon icon--white-icon "></i>                  
    {{event?.date.start | date:'EEEE, MMMM d, y, H:mm:s a'}}
</p>
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/1xhyem4MDUhHSTlIVg0E